# rivets.js and [contenteditable]

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, rivets.js

I'm using backbone and rivets.js but want to use tags other than form tags for input

example

```
<h2 contenteditable="true" data-text="post.title"></h2>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: But, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Since the elements that you would normally use contenteditable on (h1, h2, p, etc.) dont fire `change` events when their text content changes, you will need to listen to a different event on these, such as `blur`, `keyup` or the HTML5 `input` event (this is your best option if you're targeting modern browsers).

To do this, you would need to write your own custom binder. Within this binder, you can reuse the same routine as the text binding, but your bind/unbind callbacks will obviously differ.

```
rivets.binders.content = {
  routine: rivets.binders.text,
  bind: function(el) {
    var self = this
    this.callback = function() {
      rivets.config.adapter.publish(self.model, self.keypath, el.textContent)
    }
    el.addEventListener('input', this.callback, false)
  },
  unbind: function(el) {
    el.removeEventListener('input', this.callback, false)
  }
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yLQY/5/) showing this custom binder in use (only tested in Chrome 22 and Safari 6).